# CSS List item extra padding on Mac Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have this simple list item that works correctly in Chrome and Firefox on a PC, on Mac Safari the text has a height issue and it is not vertically centered within the container...

```css
li {
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background:grey;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px;
    list-style:none;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        CLICK ON ME
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background:grey;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px;
    list-style:none;
    <!-- Added -->
       display: -webkit-inline-box; 
      -webkit-box-pack: center; 
      -webkit-box-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        CLICK ON ME
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
/* Safari and Chrome */
.myClass {
color:red;
}

/* Safari only override */
::i-block-chrome,.myClass {
color:blue;
}
}
```

found this somewhere else  you give a styling to the attribute only at chrome and safari and then u overwrite the chrome styling

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, there was some extra space, I was unable to get rid of. I tried many things and finally using a different font solved the issue.